# Why does using Ctrl+C keyboard interrupt crashes the code?

Tags: python, keyboard, interrupt

I just used Ctrl+C while writing my code to copy and paste some code. But after that, my code stopped running due to a keyboard interrupt. My code is compiled and has no errors. I tried it another time without Ctrl+C in a different file but it shows the same error.

```
filename = input('Enter Project Name: ')
codeLine = input(filename + '>')
varDict = {}
varList = []
constDict = {}
constList = []
codeLine = codeLine.strip()
codeLineList = codeLine.split()
while True:
    if codeLine.endswith(";"):
        codeLine = codeLine.rstrip(codeLine[-1])
        if len(codeLineList) == 2:
            if codeLineList[1] == "is":
                varName = (codeLine.split("is")[0]).strip()
                varValue = (codeLine.split("is")[1]).strip()
                varDict[varName] = varValue
                print(varDict)
```

And I am getting the following result.

```
Enter Project Name: hi
hi>i is k;
```

Nothing seems to happen after that. When I debugged the code, I found this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/ajgameboy/PycharmProjects/mylang/main.py", line 9, in <module>
        codeLine = input(fileName + ">")
    KeyboardInterrupt
    Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Comment: CTRL-C and it's brothers, sends special characters to the console, so you can't always use these as they are. Later in your development, you will learn signal handling, and these stuff will become useful. For now, just use the mouse. (CTRL-C sends the stop command, it's not an error, hence `KeyboardInterrupt`)

Comment: The `while True:` will run forever if you don't break out of it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking CTRL-C in Python raises a KeyboardInterrupt exception. This is a way for the user to manually raise an error and interrupt the program. If you don't want this to happen you'll have to copy and paste without using CTRL-C.